# What to do if I'm being bullied by students?

Tags: teaching, united-kingdom

I've recently been the subject of bullying by a group of students. I taught a difficult module alongside another module, which was taught by somebody else. The other module was much easier and offered huge amounts of support. Students described having their hands held in this module. One student told me that this module felt like students were being treated as newbies, whereas my module felt like they were being treated as second year students at a Russell Group university. The university where I work is more teaching focused.

Having heard feedback from students, I think that the tasks I set them were quite challenging, and I don't think they were used to it. I'm still adjusting to the level that the students are operating at in this university, and were I to I teach in the module again, I would adjust the level.

However, the main issue is that students posted rude, personal and abusive feedback in the module evaluations and also posted nasty comments on the module forum. I also got nasty emails from some students, and although I passed this up to management, nothing was done and I was left to deal with this alone.

It has affected my self esteem and my confidence as a lecturer. I've always had plenty of good feedback before and I've always felt competent in my role. I don't know if I have any rights in terms of being bullied by students, but one student has just told me that there is a Facebook group where I was being slated and there were really personal comments. The student I spoke to today described it as a bit of a hate group, directed at me. One student even copied an email that I had sent her (a photograph of it) and posted it on a Facebook group. I'm not sure if this contravenes any confidentiality regulations.

Anyway, I just wondered if anyone else had experienced this and if anyone had any advice. I've been teaching for 10 years and I was on the verge of quitting my job, and I don't feel like I can easily face teaching these students again. On a personal level, I see it as an opportunity to develop greater resilience, but I can't help the fact that it really feels undermining and threatening to be in this situation.

Any advice or support would be appreciated.

Comment: Get used to students not liking you... grow a thick skin. You're not there to make friends, you're there to be fair and teach a tough subject. You will have many students not like you because your course is challenging. Read the feedback impartially, and see if there is a common theme that needs attention that you can improve upon. Otherwise, disregard it as grumbling students. You'll have a tough career if you take personal offense to every negative grumbling from students, and an even worse career if you try to fight each one.

Comment: As a pseudo-side-note, depending on the content of the Facebook group you may have a case with Facebook r.e. targeted attacks.

Comment: @SnakeDoc This is not very helpful advice given that the OP may be working in a professional environment where these things cannot so easily be shrugged off. Do you actually know anything about working in UK academia?

Comment: @YemonChoi What about the OP's post makes you think this is some sort of professional environment? Student's not liking a tough professor isn't somehow unique to the UK.

Comment: @Dharma Jane, respect to you. You are brave and great to have stuck with teaching for 10 years. SnakeDoc means to help you, not disparage you. A thick skin is a blessing and it is essential for survival sake and also for your own good. It really takes time to cultivate a thick skin. First thing first always, banish all fears from your mind. Banish hurts too. That will all take practice and you will learn that, gradually. Good luck. Once you have cultivated a thick skin over time, you will find living so much easier.

Answer (score 40):

In short, the behaviour of your students is not acceptable - no matter how good or bad your teaching was.

If something like this were to happen at my university, I as vice dean for teaching would invite the whole group for a face-to-face meeting and explain to them how adults should solve problems.

In fact, this is something you should aim for, since the problem will persist and affect others as well, since the students' behaviour will not change.

We had good success with early feedback opportunities (not just the end term evaluation), micro-evaluations (anonymous feedback which can be a one-liner) which are discussed with the whole group, an honest open door policy, and with involving student organizations and representatives early on. Some course formats have to be explained to students over and over again... This might be helpful in the future, but won't help for now.

If you are still teaching this course, I'd suggest an intervention (if possible with the help of another neutral professor) where you address the problem in front of the class. If possible, summon an extra meeting which does not take place in your usual teaching room. 
For such a setting, I would suggest just asking the students about feedback regarding your lecture, but ask them to follow commonly accepted [feedback rules](https://www.learning.ox.ac.uk/media/global/wwwadminoxacuk/localsites/oxfordlearninginstitute/documents/overview/rsv/Guidelines_for_giving_and_receiving_feedback.pdf). Afterwards, tell them what you took as the take home message from the feedback.

Afterwards, you should tell them that you prefer direct communication about any issues.

In the best case, they should be ashamed afterwards...

Answer (score 25):

I'm sorry to say this, but - as I see it, **I don't think you were bullied**.

You got negative (individual) feedback, and perhaps some of the messages were even nasty like you said they were. People may have even complained about you in a Facebook group (which, if I understand correctly, you have not actually read the contents of). That does not constitute bullying.

Remember, you are the person in a position of power relative to these students. You set their grades, you can make demands of them, you decide if they face a module that's easier or harder.

If they had contacted your friends or family to deride you; if they had spread lies about you; if had tried to publicize their derisive comments to as many people as possible on campus; if they had threatened you with some kind of retribution, or been physically violent towards you; etc. - then you might have called it bullying.

It's perfectly legitimate to feel shaken, insulted, hurt, by their behavior; but it seems to have been within the bounds of what you should just tolerate.

So: Bear in mind the positive feedback that you often get; it's an assurance that you can and do teach well, in most situations. Talk about this experience with close friends and colleagues, or your spouse if you have one. In fact, given the severity of what you describe, perhaps you should consult a psychologist, for more personalized advice about how to handle this situation. It seems to have touched a nerve that runs much deeper than the experience with these students.

**Edit**: Note that even if you don't agree with my point of view, it's a point of view which many may adopt, given the information we have. And if there are many whom you can't convince you were wronged, your justification for any retaliatory action or complaint would be very shaky. Try to turn the tables and see what this scenario sounds like from the students' point of view.

Comment: I agree that there's a line between private communications between students and actions that directly engage the OP, but there is also a line between comments in a general-purpose group and the formation of a dedicated group to discuss an individual teacher. It doesn't have to be bullying to be inappropriate behaviour that should (in an ideal world, anyway) be addressed by the university in some form. (Other than that, +1 - there is a real need to objectively consider just how bad the behaviour is, ideally with input from external observers.)

Comment: @E.P.: 1. OP did not say there was a Facebook group formed especially for discussing him, he said he had been derided. Actually, he doesn't even quite say that, he says he has been told this is the case. 2. If a students feel there's a problem with a teacher of theirs and form a Facebook group to discuss it, even that would still not be bullying. Had they been coordinating how to get back at him or smear his name in public, that would have been bullying.

Comment: 3. OP has been rather unspecific and vague about what exactly people had wrote him, said to him or said about him. I have this feeling that others might characterize what was said as "harsh" or "unfair" but perhaps not inappropriate. 4. Something rather extreme has to happen, in my view, for university authorities to start curtailing student speech; and even it had been inappropriate, it's very unlikely from what OP described that things were as bad as that.

Comment: Indeed, I agree there's a high chance that this is unlikely to be bullying. But I'll say it again: it does not have to be bullying to be inappropriate behaviour. And there's a huge range of possible institutional responses that do not entail curtailing speech, starting with a frank chat between a tutor and the students about how to handle adversity in a professional way (particularly if it *does* turn out to be the case that a dedicated "hate group" (OP's term) has been set up). I'm amazed with your virulent reaction at someone (mostly) agreeing with you, though.

Comment: @E.P.: The reaction was due to the suggestion that university authorities may need to be involved. I tend to be touchy about the prospect of exercise of coercive power. Anyway, I agree with your last comment.

Comment: einpoklum, is there any reason why you're consistly using the male pronoun for the OP?

Comment: @YemonChoi: Sorry, subconscious cultural bias.

Comment: OP says she's been teaching for ten years. I'm sure she's encountered her fair share of negative and even nasty feedback and can tell the difference between this and bullying. What's the point in downplaying her experience and her current situation?

Comment: @henning: It's the other way around. OP has describ ed events which do not constitute bullying, but is up-playing them to be considered bullying and is considering or is being encouraged to initiate disciplinary procedures against some of her students. She asked what to do in this situation, and I reflected how it comes off and what I believe would be relevant/legitimate.

Comment: Hi, I clarified the bullying situation below. Also, colleagues of mine came to me because they were concerned about what students were saying and posting on a university forum about me, and described the situation as being a witch hunt. Other colleagues teaching my module have been supportive and cannot understand why do students are behaving in this way, and have apologized that I am going through this. I am certainly not up playing anything. I'm not new to this game, but I'm new to this behaviour

Comment: I didn't feel that it was necessary to outline exactly what students said about me and exactly what they have done. To be honest, I don't really want to relive it or put it in black and white here, but suffice it to say that my experience is real and was not up for evaluation here. I do appreciate the supportive comments that I've received, as well as some of the critical advice. I do not appreciate my experience being questioned, though.

Comment: @DharmaJane: I answered based on what you wrote. Your experience is apparently different, but remember your students' experience might be quite different than your own.

Comment: Feels pretty important people remember that just because they're students, doesn't make it any more acceptable. If this was your colleagues behaving this way - it 100% would be an HR issue, considered as bullying. The fact they are students, does not lessen that.

Comment: @Bilkokuya: Behavior by someone who is under your power, e.g. a student, can and must be tolerated more than behavior by someone who is not. This is part of the responsibility of having power on someone. And this is doubly the case when the offensive behavior is by people who don't have power over _you_. So, indeed, from colleagues - this could well have been considered at least harrasment and possibly bullying. Not so from students.

Comment: @einpoklum Do you actually know about the NSS, the TEF, and so on? Or professional life teaching in a UK university which is so-called "teaching intensive"?

Comment: @einpoklum Because if not, then I don't think it's very productive to keep challenging the OP on her diagnosis of her immediate situation, based on your remote reading and general preconceptions.

Answer (score 13):

Capable lecturers, especially if they come from research-heavy institutions, treat students as copies of themselves - assuming maximum competence, enthusiasm, skill and perseverance. But you cannot assume that. If you are lucky, you have 5-10% of students coming close to that level.

But you are a teacher, and you have to serve the grand majority. So, your next task is learning how to teach effectively. Most students react well to being taken seriously.

So, rather than semi-formal evaluations, one thing that works well is getting face-to-face response from students early on about whether the course is too easy, too fast, etc. If they say it is way too difficult, you have a gauge that you are probably too fast. You then may want to slow down. If they say it is "a bit too hard", you are in good shape, because you most likely want to stretch them - make it clear to them, though. Students, again, in my experience, respond well to explanations why the course is not and *should not* be too easy, as long as they see a reasonable chance to pass it and serious effort on the side of the lecturer to help them achieve the desired level.

The key is and remains: communication. However, it is the face-to-face that matters. Once communication begins to go on behind your back, we get to a more problematic situation.

And so, now to the matter of bullying. This is, unfortunately, a self-reinforcing process. It is doubtful that this can be stopped short of a very serious warning by the university, but I suspect anything short of a direct threat of violence will not mobilise the department to your protection.

One idea is really to block any of these negative messages. You are not likely to be helped by the department. There is almost nothing you can do to stop a collective of students to run their bullying activity against you, once it has taken off. But you can minimise the effect on you. If hate-mail is sent to you, archive it, but do not read it in detail. Do not respond to statements about people having Facebook pages about you. Far too often, these people project their own shortcomings onto whoever made them face them.

The past cohort is pretty much a lost cause. Cut your losses. However, for the new year, adapt your pedagogy, get feedback early and often, even face-to-face. Do not be subservient, but demonstrate that you are interested in students' opinion, even if you may not always be able to follow their requests. Finding the right balance is a learning process on your side. With this, hopefully, this negative experience of yours will soon fade into an indistinct past.

Comment: I know you’re trying to be helpful, but most of this answer feels like victim-blaming. OP seems to be asking for _support_ and advice about how to deal with the abuse, not advice about how to teach and communicate better with her students to avoid future abuse, which is most of what your answer contains, and sounds critical and frankly not very supportive. Have you noticed that you don’t even mention the bullying until the fifth paragraph of your answer? And that nowhere do you say (as another answer does) that this abuse is wrong and unacceptable regardless of the level of OP’s teaching?

Comment: @DanRomik I know that the word "victim-blaming" is in fashion today. However, I can only talk from my experience and that is that you can change yourself, but not others. Other responses deal with the bullying, so I did not feel it is necessary to replicate their response, but rather add a novel perspective to it. It should be obvious (although in these times every thing seems to have to be spelt out - "Contents may be hot") that bullying is totally unacceptable. Totally. Absolutely. But when you are verbally mugged, and nobody helps you (maybe not even your dept. as some others suggest here).

Comment: @DanRomik then, I think the main point is to help OP to find ways to avoid being in such a situation and to deal with it as it is. I think that we have this idea today that somehow every negative interaction can and will be sorted by appealing to a higher authority. The present case is so dire that, if there is such support, the OP can and should use it. However, this is not necessarily the case, and, in any case, prevention is better than cure. Let's face it, the likely reason why OP is in such a position is the fact that students are customers and that the balance of power has completely..

Comment: @DanRomik tipped drastically towards accommodating students, whether they are right or not. Such a situation would have been unthinkable when I studied, it was very clear who wielded the power then - it was not the students; but today, the departments are likely to accommodate the students rather than the teachers. No, I am most definitely *not* victim-blaming, but rather make suggestions to turn students into OP's allies rather than enemies. If you feel the response does not serve OP, I am prepared to delete it. I have done my best to offer a constructive, tested, working solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Yes, I was not questioning your good intentions but was simply offering my feedback as one reader. It is not for me to say whether you should delete your answer, I’m only one person with an opinion, and can well be wrong about what OP or others will find helpful and what not.

Comment: @DanRomik Indeed, I got that - and one should never assume that one's message comes across correctly; unfortunately, the comments tend to vanish, so they do not always help to fine-tune reception of a response. We'll see how the votes go, and decide from there.

Comment: Downvoted: The question is about how to deal with bullying. Unless you're suggesting that making students think too hard—even MUCH too hard—turns them into bullies, the first half of this answer is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffE The OP makes clear that they believe there is a link between the challenge of the class and the campaign run against them. I am suggesting is that the lecturer communicate to the class why challenge is necessary. Had the OP not talked about the link, I never would have suggested this response. New lecturers are particularly vulnerable to bad feedback (which here degenerated into collective bullying) from students and need to build up their case bottom-up, since departments nowadays are often not ready to stand behind them. I wonder about OP's opinion on the relevance of this response.

Comment: This is good advice. A teacher should not assume the students to be as knowledgeable or as interested as they are. Also in my experience many young teaching assistants seem to do that (including myself once or twice when I was younger) which can end up being frustrating for a majority of the students who are not at that same high level.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs  OP does say that have been teaching for 10 years, and had positive reviews at a previous university.  So I don't know that writing about them as a "young lecturer".

Comment: @StevenGubkin Good point, I overlooked that. On the other hand, even removing that, my main suggestion, I believe, stands - OP moved to a university with significantly more emphasis on teaching, so the mindset shift required may still be the same. I will edit my response, however, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @StevenGubkin no one assumes the OP was that one young lecturer. It was just an observation that I think many people who have seen teaching being done at university have made.

Comment: I'm not young, but students ( and other people who don't know me well)  tend to estimate that I am in my 20s, where as I am quite a lot older than that. I get asked for ID on a regular basis and I am in my mid to late thirties.

Comment: @DharmaJane For some reason, I thought you may have been - I changed this in my response, sorry about my mistake. However, looking young may play a role in lack of respect. The balance of power has been so systematically upset in the UK that, rather than just "defang" academic tyrants, it has now equipped students with unreasonable amount of power. You have my sympathy - I hope my response is nonetheless of any use to you. You can see above it was quite controversial, and I was quite interested to know in whether my response was in any form useful to you.

Comment: Ascertain whether your students actually come to you with a student mentality or a customer mentality. Work from there.

Answer (score 7):

I can only answer for the U.S.

Here is a sample excerpt from a Code of Conduct.  This one is from the University of Wisconsin:

> Harassment or bullying is language or conduct that is unwelcome and sufficiently severe, persistent, or pervasive such that it could reasonably be expected to create an intimidating, hostile, or offensive environment, or has the purpose or effect of unreasonably interfering with a person's academic or work performance, or a person's ability to participate in or benefit from the university's programs, services, opportunities, or activities, when viewed through both an objective and subjective standard. This includes harassment or bullying that occurs through electronic means, such as electronic media, the internet, social networks, blogs, cell phones, or text messages.

From your description, this seems apt.  The start page for the Code of Conduct gives contact information for "Community Standards & Student Conduct."

Please, file a complaint.  And check the policies at your institution.  If you find something relevant, cite it in your complaint.  If you don't, propose that something be added.

Next time: when you start seeing some red flags -- if something feels a bit off -- start documenting, and inform the office that promotes healthy and respectful student conduct (or your department, as the case may be) that you're getting a bad feeling and will update them in a week as to whether things are worse, the same or better.  Establishing a line of communication BEFORE things reach crisis point can be helpful.

*Why should you file a complaint?*  Part of being a good university citizen means providing specific negative feedback about something that is not right, so the university can work continually on improving the study and work environment.

**Edit**: Additional remarks.

1. The climate in your university will only become more positive if the members of the university community work together toward that goal.
2. Find a teaching mentor or an office that provides pedagogy support for teachers.  Spend 5% of your time reading about teaching and observing other teachers and keep a journal about your observations and your reading.  As you gain theoretical knowledge and practical experience your confidence will grow.

Answer (score 4):

The only practical advice here is:  Get used to it.  The system isn't fair and it isn't nice and the University doesn't care.  These things are emotionally crippling and no other career has to put up with this nonsense.  Every semester, you get your evaluations back and 99 of them are glowing, but that one immature, soon-to-drop-out-anyway leaves you profane and false feedback, and your week is ruined.  It's wrong, but it isn't going to change.  So the only thing you can do is work on your reaction to it.  What I have done over the years is to force myself to think about the 99 every time I start dwelling on the 1.  It sort of works.  And alcohol helps too.

Having said that, your situation points up a deep problem in academia.  With sites like Rate-a-Prof and Reddit and GroupMe, the students have a ready venue for their shark-feeds.  The University should exert itself to fight these things.  Student grades (which no one cares about) are somehow protected by FERPA, while faculty ratings are "public record."  And somehow, it's OK with your employer that these teenagers can slander you and your work with impunity.

If someone started up a website called Rate-A-Dean, and let faculty treat the deans like the students treat faculty, you can bet our collective TIAA-Cref accounts that the University would send in armies of lawyers and get the thing shut down with extreme prejudice.

(I just looked at Obu's answer and I'm shocked.  I've never run into an administrator who would take action in such a case.  I'm glad to hear of it, but I think this is rare.  If your admins take up your case, then I think you're very lucky indeed.)

Well, here's another practical thing you can do:  Give informal evaluations early and frequently.  If the students are allowed to vent early on, it tempers their immature behavior when the formal evaluations roll around.  Since they get to vent, there is less urgency to start a Reddit thread for a shark feed.  Since they've already ranted once, they don't feel so much like ranting again.  You can pitch the informal evaluations whether you read them or not.  Their still immature and still unfair, but now you control the channel.

Comment: Yes i agree - we faculty : lecturers are a cost to the university, while the students are the source of the money, the phrase “don’t bite the hand that feeds you” comes to mind...

Comment: @SolarMike  That's the way they think.  I've pointed out that I teach 700 students per year and each pays $2000 for the privilege.  So I bring in $1.4 million dollars of income each year for the university.  That's more than the football program.  Yet I'm a "cost."

Comment: "Give informal evaluations early and frequently" - is probably the most important advice in this response.

Comment: -1 "alcohol helps too"

Comment: @DanielR.Collins a nice beer at the end of the day or have you done -1 as you think he is alcoholic?

Comment: This wasn't about one rude comment in a course evalutation, nor about one difficult student. The situation as described by OP is bullying, online and offline, committed by a group. "Get used to it" is not a helpful answer in this situation, I fear.

Comment: @henning It was about the emotional turmoil.  The number of students is irrelevant.  The OP says that she has plenty of good feedback.  So it certainly is a case of many good and few bad.  And "get used to it" is the ONLY thing she can do.  It's not going to stop, no matter how much the rest of us commiserate.   Another factor is that the world perceives that the lecturer has power while the students are powerless.  (If they only knew!) They won't believe that the lecturer is bullied.

Comment: I downvoted this answer for two reasons. First, alcohol is of no help in this situation: it could be a palliative, but doesn't solve the problem (and I'm quite a good drinker). Second, your answer is more of a rant and it's totally focussed on the US system (FERPA?), but there is no indication that the OP is from the US.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano  The central problem is the emotional turmoil.  A palliative is exactly the thing called for.  You can only control your own actions, not the actions of others.  Suggestions on how to control the actions of the students are the unhelpful ones.  But thanks for explaining.

Comment: I do think that alcohol in fun situations is quite different from being used as a palliative. The latter is actually dangerous, it should not be recommended in a response. One can suggest sports, yoga, or other similar activity, but alcohol is seriously bad advice. Maybe the responder has a good self-discipline, but there are enough people for whom beginning to drown sorrow in alcohol this is a slippery slope. I would remove this from the response.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano OP all but [confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_Group) that they're in the UK. I agree that the US-centered rant on FERPA is rather off the mark.

Comment: @E.P.  It's not a "rant of FERPA".  The point was the inconsistency.  For some reason, my ratings of students are regarded as private, but the students' ratings of me are "public record."  I was for FERPA when it came out.  I'm now allowed to hang up on irate, helicopter parents.  To characterize my comment as a "rant on FERPA" is just an admission that you didn't read my comment thoughtfully.

Comment: The point is that those matters change, often significantly, from country to country, and particularly between the US and Europe. Your point may well be true in the US and it may even hold in the UK, but the fact that you're explicitly talking about a different situation than the OP's indicates that you *don't* know the standing of those issues in the UK and does huge damage to the usefulness and on-topicness of this answer. I was explaining my downvote as a courtesy to you, since the answer has valuable additions, but if you really can't see those distinctions then I have nothing else to add.

Comment: @E.P.  The details might be different, but the situations are the same.  The students are trashing the prof on a public forum.  The university will probably do nothing.  In the US it's "FERPA" vs. "public record," but it doesn't matter what you call it.  You have a distinction without a difference.

Comment: TBH, I think your answer is too general to apply to OP's case specifically. You do make several good points though. I'm glad there's no rate-a-prof where I live and work. @SolarMike: In many countries, student contribution to university income is not terribly significant. In my alma mater it was under 10% of the general budget.

Comment: @einpoklum you bring up a good point about how student contribution to university income, and hence the importance of "customer satisfaction", varies between countries. In the UK, which is where I infer the OP is working, student fees can make up a large amount of what a department brings in to the university, and universities are increasingly reliant on the income from those fees

Comment: @einpoklum some teaching establishments are 100% student funded, and some of us work in those so we see the pressure of students comments much more directly than you do - the « it’s ok I’ll ignore it » option you have is not an option for those who are 100% funded....

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues here:

- Student comments on feedback forms
- Abusive language in direct communication
- Comments on a facebook group.

There is little last on of these unless the language would meet some definition of Hate Speech: i.e. comments were based on your race, gender, sexual orientation or other protected characteristic. In which case it would be a police matter.

On the first of these - student feedback is useful where it comments on the teaching it self in a constructive way that can be used to change the teaching. Thus our office filters out purely person feedback before it is pass on to us: comments on dress sense, personal manner, appearance, sex, race etc are not constructive and cause only harm. The filtering was felt necessary because such comments disproportionately affected women and lecturers from minority groups. However, comments that do address teaching in an actionable way, even if they do so with potentially offensive language, are left in.

For the direct communications I would start by giving the student a warning - tell them that such impolite communication is unprofessional and potentially harassing and that you will address their concerns if they phrase them in a polite and constructive manner. Point our that if they did this to their boss at work, they'd find themselves in trouble very quickly. If they ignore this
report them to the HoD/Head tutor with evidence. If you receive no response, particularly if this happens repeatedly I'd talk to your union rep (you are in the union right?).

Answer (score 2):

I moved to the UK from a different country and got some really harsh evaluations in my first year, even though I also had quite some teaching experience before that. The level of students (especially at a teaching-oriented university) is unfortunately not very high.

I am disappointed about the management though. Did you mean professors or people outside your department? In my experience, nothing good comes from outside the department... One thing I would recommend is to discuss this with your colleagues (at the same level as you). They might have similar experiences and might even have suggestions for how to handle this. I think it is not unusual to get bad evaluations in your first year.

I assume that your teaching evaluations go onto your record and that you are therefore worried about them, especially as you may still be on probation. The good thing is that you have time to recover, and you will be able to show a positive trend over the years. Anyway, the most important thing to realize is that it is not you - it is the students. If you adapt (dumb things down enough where possible) your evaluations WILL improve. It is sad that this is necessary, but given the level of students that are accepted to many universities, it seems to be the only way.

Also, these students will move on soon enough and you will be able to make a better impression on the next batch. Having said this, the behaviour of this batch really is unacceptable. Do the students have personal tutors that you could contact?

Answer (score 1):

One of the silver linings of these cases is that you can be confident that, over time, these students will rotate out of the university and you will still be there.  For that reason, I wouldn't concern yourself too much with whether or not the nasty comments you received on your teaching constitute "bullying", and I wouldn't bother pursuing a complaint within the department.  Just treat it as a learning experience and bear in mind that some university students act in ways that are immature and unprofessional.  When they are older and are experiencing the difficulties of the workforce themselves, I would expect that they will look back on this and feel ashamed of their behaviour.

If it were me, I would just ignore the sniping --- students like this are immature adolescents, and grown-up professionals don't concern ourselves with the catty social media sniping of adolescents.  To any mature reader, social media posts like this will reflect poorly on them, but not on you.  I suspect that your department probably did nothing because they understand this reality, and they figure they can let this one slide.  Unless you have seen indications to the contrary, I wouldn't take this to mean that they don't support you; assume that they have confidence in your teaching unless they tell you otherwise.

Most importantly, don't let this bad experience shatter your confidence in your teaching.  It sounds like you probably didn't calibrate the course to quite the right level of difficulty, and students got the shits with that and lashed out in an immature way --- it happens.  Over time you will learn to pitch your course at a level that is challenging enough, but with adequate support so that the students do not feel lost and angry.  Departments expect that lecturers may sometimes have a bad semester where teaching doesn't go as planned, especially if they are new to a course.  Over time you will gain the experience to command a classroom well, engage your students at a correct level, and have better teaching experiences.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in an institution where you are assessed based on your student feedback, you have two choices.

1. You can leave and get a job where you will be supported and developed by your employer.
2. You can make your course so easy that even the dumbest students get B's and spend way over your paid time to hold their hands (when they want it, rather than in office hours). But over time the students will get dumber and you will lose the will to live.

So, I would recommend looking for a new job, probably outside of academia.

Comment: I guess your answer is well intentioned, but perhaps it's been downvoted because some people found it glib? (FWIW I didn't downvote or upvote it)

Comment: Perhaps that is what they think, it is based on solid experience.

Comment: Well said.  This is exactly the choices I am facing.  My institution (foreign university operating in China) make decisions on performance assessments and contract renewals based on student evaluations.   I will come back and post more when I am finally gone.